# Compact convergence of a sequence of holomorphic functions in terms of semi norms

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

How can the compact convergence for a sequence of holomorphic functions be expressed in terms of seminorms? Any help would be great as this is for study.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $K$ is a compact subset of the open set $V$ define $$\rho_K(f)=\sup_{x\in K}|f(z)|.\quad(f\in H(V)).$$Then $\rho_K$ is a seminorm on $H(V)$, and $f_n\to f$ compactly if and only if $\rho_K(f_n-f)\to0$ for every $K$.